# How to change Language of PrimeVue Datatable Buttons and Filters

Tags: vue.js, filter, datatable, primevue

How can I change the language of Primefaces PrimeVue Datatable Buttons and filters?

These are standard fields of primeVue datatable:

[image]

Filter:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post code in images

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
         * Filter option translation
         */
        const matchModesOptions = [
            {label: 'Gleich...', value: FilterMatchMode.EQUALS},
            {label: 'Nicht gleich...', value: FilterMatchMode.NOT_EQUALS},
            {label: 'Beginnt mit...', value: FilterMatchMode.STARTS_WITH},
            {label: 'Endet mit...', value: FilterMatchMode.ENDS_WITH},
            {label: 'Beinhaltet...', value: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS}
        ]
```

There is an mistake at the documentation of primevue. This is how it works.