# How to change language of primevue filters

Tags: vue.js, primevue

How can I manage to change the Filter labels in Prime Vue?

I have found a similiar if not the same question without a working answer.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68557178/how-to-change-language-of-primevue-datatable-buttons-and-filters) has an answer which states

```
const matchModesOptions = [
            {label: 'Gleich...', value: FilterMatchMode.EQUALS},
            {label: 'Nicht gleich...', value: FilterMatchMode.NOT_EQUALS},
            {label: 'Beginnt mit...', value: FilterMatchMode.STARTS_WITH},
            {label: 'Endet mit...', value: FilterMatchMode.ENDS_WITH},
            {label: 'Beinhaltet...', value: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS}
        ]
```

Although, used on this first example of the PrimeVue website
https://primevue.org/datatable/filter
it doesn't seem to work.

```
    filters: {
              global: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS },
              name: { operator: FilterOperator.AND, constraints: [{ label: "Test", value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.STARTS_WITH }] },
              "country.name": { operator: FilterOperator.AND, constraints: [{ value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.STARTS_WITH }] },
              representative: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.IN },
              date: { operator: FilterOperator.AND, constraints: [{ label: "Test", filterLocale: "de-DE", value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.DATE_IS }] }
}
```

Does anyone know a solution to add/customize those labels? (Also, there is an "Add Rule" button which would also need to be translated but the docs do not state anything about this...)

[image: Image of filters]

Comment: not able to test this but I think https://primevue.org/configuration should be able to change it. (Scroll down to Locale Options -> startsWith, ...)

Answer (score 1):

you can use PrimeVue config options

```
import PrimeVue, { PrimeVueConfiguration } from 'primevue/config';
  app.use(PrimeVue, {
    locale:{ matchAll: "جميع الشروط", .... }
  } as PrimeVueConfiguration);
```

alternatively you may modify only a portion of it like this:

```
import PrimeVue, { PrimeVueConfiguration, defaultOptions } from 'primevue/config';

app.use(PrimeVue, {
    locale: {
      ...defaultOptions.locale,
      matchAll: "جميع الشروط" }
} as PrimeVueConfiguration);
```

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

this away by vuetify3:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
      tableHeaders: [
        {
          align: 'start',
          key: 'name',
          sortable: false,
          title: this.$t('nutrition.dessertHeader'),
        },
        {
          key: 'calories',
          title: this.$t('nutrition.caloriesHeader'),
        },
        {
          key: 'fat',
          title: this.$t('nutrition.fatHeader'),
        },
        {
          key: 'carbs',
          title: this.$t('nutrition.carbsHeader'),
        },
        {
          key: 'protein',
          title: this.$t('nutrition.proteinHeader'),
        },
        {
          key: 'iron',
          title: this.$t('nutrition.ironHeader'),
        },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: 1,
        },
        //...
      ],
    };
  },
  created() {
    // Set translations as data properties
    this.$data.nutrition = {
      title: this.$t('nutrition.title'),
      search: this.$t('nutrition.search'),
      dessertHeader: this.$t('nutrition.dessertHeader'),
      caloriesHeader: this.$t('nutrition.caloriesHeader'),
      fatHeader: this.$t('nutrition.fatHeader'),
      carbsHeader: this.$t('nutrition.carbsHeader'),
      proteinHeader: this.$t('nutrition.proteinHeader'),
      ironHeader: this.$t('nutrition.ironHeader'),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      {{ $t('nutrition.title') }}
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        :label="$t('nutrition.search')"
        single-line
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table :headers="tableHeaders" :items="desserts" :search="search"></v-data-table>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This changes table headers, not filters, right?

Answer (score 0):

After a long journey through the source code of PrimeVue v3.28.0, I finally found the method for labeling custom filters, although it is still a clumsy solution.

As you can see, there is a computed method called `matchModes()` in the definition of the ColumnFilter component, located at line 2153 in `datatable.js`.

```
matchModes() {
    return (
        this.matchModeOptions ||
        this.$primevue.config.filterMatchModeOptions[this.type].map((key) => {
            return { label: this.$primevue.config.locale[key], value: key };
        })
    );
}
```

This method is used as the `options` parameter for the Dropdown component at line 2360. The label attribute of the elements returned by `matchModes()` is what we ultimately want to display.

```
vue.createBlock(_component_CFDropdown, {
    key: 0,
    options: $options.matchModes,
    modelValue: fieldConstraint.matchMode,
    class: "p-column-filter-matchmode-dropdown",
    optionLabel: "label",
    optionValue: "value",
    "aria-label": $options.filterConstraintAriaLabel,
    "onUpdate:modelValue": $event => ($options.onMenuMatchModeChange($event, i))
  }, null, 8, ["options", "modelValue", "aria-label", "onUpdate:modelValue"])
```

However, according to the definition of the `matchModes()` method above, if the filter we define does not belong to any `dataType` defined in `primevue.config.filterMatchModeOptions`, it will directly return a plain string without a label, which results in no text being displayed.

A temporary solution, written using the Composition API, is as follows, assuming that I have registered a custom filter for a custom date field that uses [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

In the `<script>` block:

```
import { usePrimeVue } from 'primevue/config';

const PrimeVue = usePrimeVue();

PrimeVue.config.filterMatchModeOptions.MomentDateTime = ['filterByDateTimeEquals'];

PrimeVue.config.locale.filterByDateTimeEquals = PrimeVue.config.locale.dateIs;

FilterService.register('filterByDateTimeEquals', (datetime, value) => {
    if (!value) return true;
    return TimeService.Backend.toJSDate(datetime).getTime() == value.getTime();
});
```

In the `<template>` block, part omitted:

```
<DataTable>
    ...
    <!--Here, a dataType is added-->
    <Column field="birthDate" header="Birth Date" dataType="MomentDateTime">
        <template #body="{ data }">
            {{ TimeService.Frontend.fromDate(data.birthDate) }}
        </template>
        <template #filter="{ filterModel }">
            <Calendar v-model="filterModel.value" dateFormat="yy/mm/dd" :placeholder="moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD')" />
        </template>
    </Column>
    ...
</DataTable>
```

However, this solution is still not elegant enough. I have already raised an [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues/4017) on GitHub to request the development team to address this matter, waiting for their response.